# Adding metadata to multiple files in batch/simultaneous process using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, feature-class, metadata

I have a `feature class` that has `metadata` that I would like to add to `31` other feature classes in ArcGIS Pro 3.

Is there a way/tool to add metadata in batch or simultaneously, so I don't have to add it individually to each feature class one by one?

I did find [Creating metadata for multiple datasets simultaneously in ArcCatalog](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12613) but it is in reference to ArcGIS Desktop 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import metadata from one dataset to another using the import button here:

[image: Button]

I would say that's the easiest way when you have only a few datasets to update.

If you have many datasets you want to update then currently the only solution is to script it and this is discussed in detail on the [arcpy metadata page](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/metadata/metadata-class.htm#).

If you have access to ArcMap then there are geoprocessing tools that can be used to automate processing using ModelBuilder but no such equivalent tools exist in ArcGIS Pro. You could of cause always suggest it to Esri as an [idea](https://community.esri.com/t5/custom/page/page-id/arcgis-ideas), I would vote for it!

Comment: I just found out that the model you provided in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/436769/extract-points-by-multipolygon-and-have-separate-points-output) question automatically adds `metadata` from the `point featureclass` used as input in the spatial join tool to the final output `featureclasses` via `split by attributes`.